# Add a link to an image in a Javascrip

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

hello everybody!

First of all I have to tell you I'm a newbie in terms of HTML, Javascript and coding in general. But I spent last weeks to learn as much as I can.
Now, I run a website and my dev team is not workgin with me anymore, then I have to do all by myself.

My problem is: I have a sort of "big banner" and the image shown is automatically picked up based on your browser resolution (that's fine, I asked for this). Now, what I'm trying to do is to add a hyperlink to this image. I tried many thing, but I couldnt.

Please could you tell me how to edit this code?

Thank you

Miki

```
<div class="main top">
    <div class="main-holder">
        <div class="cover-holder big-img-holder" id="img-holder">
            <script>
                function randomInteger(min, max) {
                    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
                    rand = Math.round(rand);
                    return rand;
                }
                var rand = randomInteger(1, {{$lang.extras.number_screenshots_rotations}});

                var picture = document.createElement('picture');
                                    var source = document.createElement('source');
                source.srcset = '{{$config.statics_url}}/images/bg_rotations/extras-' + rand + 'bd_HD.jpg';
                source.setAttribute('media', '(max-width: 2000px)');
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = '{{$config.statics_url}}/images/bg_rotations/extras-' + rand + 'bd.jpg';

                picture.appendChild(source);
                picture.appendChild(img);
                document.getElementById('img-holder').appendChild(picture);
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: afaict, you don't add and link...?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can set a hyper link with the HTML tag `<a>`

So you could try

```
    <a href="your-URL">
        <div class="cover-holder big-img-holder" id="img-holder">
            <script>
               ...
            </script>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the script in something like

```
<a id="img-link">
```

or just change img-holder to be an `<a>` instead of a `<div>`

Then somewhere in your script set the url for that `<a>` container

```
document.getElementById("img-link").href="url";
```

There's no href attribute to an image itself, so you must provide it to `<a>`

That is if you wanna do it dynamically, if the url is always the same, just wrap your `<script>` block with this

```
<a href="#">
 <img>
</a>
```

It is easier when you know that DOM is gonna have the same structure, in this case, an image, and an `<a>` tag wrapping it, just set ids for both, and manipulate their attributes, otherwise, you can also create this `<a>` element in Javascript, and set the image with `.setChild()` to it